# Backbone application undefined error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I am just starting backbone and javascript and am receiving the following error in console.

```
players = new Dww2.Collections.Playermaps()
ReferenceError: Dww2 is not defined
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require dww2
//= require_tree ../templates
//= require_tree ./models
//= require_tree ./collections
//= require_tree ./views
//= require_tree ./routers
//= require_tree .

playermaps_router.js.coffee

class Dww2.Routers.Playermaps extends Backbone.Router

  routes:
    'playermaps': 'index'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new Dww2.Collections.Playermaps()
    @collection.reset($('#container').data('playermaps'))

  index: ->
    view = new Dww2.Views.PlayermapsIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#container').html(view.render().el)
```

playermaps.js.coffee

```
class Dww2.Collections.Playermaps extends Backbone.Collection

  url: '/playermaps'
  model: Dww2.Models.Playermap
```

dww2.js.coffee

```
window.Dww2 =
Models: {}
Collections: {}
Views: {}
Routers: {}
initialize: ->
  new Dww2.Routers.Playermaps()
  Backbone.history.start(pushState: true)

$(document).ready ->
 Dww2.initialize()
```

Comment: Does removing the `//= require_tree .` line make any difference? I've run in to odd issues occasionally with how `require_tree` adds asset files, specifically with backbone.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the following line declared?

```
players = new Dww2.Collections.Playermaps();
```

If the `players` variable is declared in an inline `<script>` element in the page it is most likely that the contents of dww2.js.coffee has not been loaded when you try and assign it a new `Dww2.Collections.Playermaps`. If this is the case `window.Dww2` wont exist yet and will be undefined.

You can fix it by creating the `Dww2.Collections.Playermaps` object in a $(document).ready function

Comment: I have the above file I just added that sits in the root of my javascripts directory..

Comment: I am typing players = new Dww2.Collections.Playermaps(); into the console and getting the error, I tried adding the above line but am still having the same issue